# How to return JSON or Ruby hash from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please consider the following method in a controller:

```
def get_navigation_from_session
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: session[:navigation]}
  end
  return session[:navigation]
end
```

What I want it to do is respond to an Ajax call and send the navigation hash if it's being asked for it.  If not, I just want it to return the hash to the ruby code that needs it.  This obviously isn't working.  How can I fix the above method to accomplish this goal?

Thank you

Comment: You should only worry about writing a response from within a controller action, not returning any sort of value.  You should alter any code that is calling the controller action and expecting a Hash in return.  It's tough to give you a good solution without understanding what you are trying to accomplish with the code.  Maybe if you post the rest of the code involved or explain what you are trying to do someone can help restructure your code.

Comment: Thanks Ogz.  I store navigation coordinates in the session, where the user is in the app.  I need to constantly be updating something in the layout based on this information, so I want to have some Ajax go through the application controller (seemed like a logical place to make a route) and find out.  I'd appreciate if you could steer me in the direction of best practices here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# this is your action method, supposed to be called via your request cycle with rendering
def get_navigation_from_session
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: get_navigation_hash_from_session }
  end
end

# a getter - maybe higher up in controller hiararchy
def get_navigation_hash_from_session
  session[:navigation]
end
```